# locate select class value having only onchange parameter in selenium java

Tags: selenium

Set As PrimaryUpdate Spec

here , I have to locate set as primary and  update spec , and so on options in this drop down , please suggest

Comment: <SELECT onchange=evalList(this) tag="select">
 <OPTION selected><OPTION value="setSpecAsPrimary('OR:com.lcs.wc.specification.FlexSpecToSeasonLink:41304381');this.selectedIndex=0">Set As Primary<OPTION value="updateSpecification('VR:com.lcs.wc.specification.FlexSpecification:41304368')">Update Spec

Comment: do you have multiple select on your page?

Comment: above code only one select within that multiple options , here select don't have name or id , so how to address using only onchnage ?

Comment: is it allows multiple selection?

Comment: its drop dwon list having multiple values in list

Comment: do you want to select only one option or more? please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select class as given below. Assume, only one select box on the page.

```
Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select"));
sel.SelectByVisibleText("Set As Primary");
sel.SelectByVisibleText("Update Spec --");//text should match exactly of the option and you select box should allows multiple selection.
```

To select image,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[@src='/Windchill/netmarkets/images/managed_collection.gif']").click();
```

Comment: can you help me to locate image as well - <A onmouseover="return overlib('Generate Tech Pack');" onmouseout="return nd();" href="javascript:generateSpecPDF('OR:com.lcs.wc.specification.FlexSpecToSeasonLink:41304381')"><IMG src="/Windchill/netmarkets/images/managed_collection.gif" border=0 tag="img"></A>

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath to locate it. If you have tried it with CLASS locator and it doesn't work try xpath. Usually relative xpath should help if not then try the long form xpath to reach /SELECT. So it could look something like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/nav/ol/li/ol/SELECT"));
```

Then use the SELECT class to select by value, visible text etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
 Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("SELECT[onchange='evalList(this)'][tag='select']")));
 sel.selectByValue("updateSpecification('VR:com.lcs.wc.specification.FlexSpecification:41304368')");
```